# jest+supertest e2e testing of API endpoints that issue HTTP requests to other endpoints

Tags: typescript, jestjs, microservices, e2e-testing, supertest

I am e2e testing my API endpoints using jest and supertest. The api endpoints are implemented in express with typescript. The problem I am dealing with is that my app is setup as microservices where some of my endpoints issue HTTP requests to other endpoints. All of those microservices are mounted in the same app for the purpose of these tests.

So I am using

```
const res = await request(app)
      .get(endpoint)
      .set('Authorization', authorization);
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
```

to fetch my endpoint. But this returns with statusCode 500 and the error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8999`. The endpoint indeed issues an HTTP request to another endpoint on the same host. I guess supertest isn't actually starting the whole app, and therefore the other api endpoints aren't available? Is there a way to solve this? I don't want to mock the other endpoint, since this should be an end-to-end test. Unittests are available too, but right now I am writing e2e snapshot tests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the port number, which is defined in config, but Supertest uses a random port number to run the app on. But you can also pass a running (listening) app to supertest's `request` so you can just use `request(app.listen(portnum)).get(endpoint)`.